# Unable to Load data from CSV to Elasticsearch using Logstash

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash, loading

I'm using Logstash 2.3.3 to load data from csv file to Elasticsearch 2.3.3.

Here is my Logstash configuration file:

```
input {
  #stdin {
   # type => "stdin-type"
  #}

  file {
    path => "/Users/hieupm/export.txt"
    start_position => "beginning"
    codec => plain {
      charset => "CP1252"
    }
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    gsub => [
      "message", "\"", " ",
      "message", " +", " ",
      "message", " ;", ";",
      "message", "; ", ";"
    ]
    lowercase => ["message"]
  }
  csv {
    columns => ["siren","raison_sociale","enseigne","cp_ville","naf","nature_juridique","code_tranche"] 
    separator => ","
  }
}

output {
  #stdout {
  #}

  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "127.0.0.1:9200"
    index => "ereputation"
    document_id => "%{siren}"
  }
}
```

The execution log (in terminal) didn't give any error but it just displayed as below and never finished

```
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 8
Pipeline main started
```

My sample data:

```
siren,raison_sociale,enseigne,cp_ville,naf,nature_juridique,code_tranche 
5420021,ETABLISSEMENTS BIQUEZ,,80100 ABBEVILLE,4669B,5710,11
5420120,STE DES SUCRERIES DU MARQUENTERRE,,62140 MARCONNELLE,1081Z,5599,11
5480082,STE BRETONNE DE TRAVAUX PUBLICS,,44600 ST NAZAIRE,4312A,5599,21
5480546,SOCIETE DE DISTRIBUTION DE PAPIER,,44350 GUERANDE,1712Z,5710,21
5520176,CARTONNAGE HERNAS,,80210 FEUQUIERES EN VIMEU,1721A,5710,21
5520242,PROSPA,,80510 LONGPRE LES CORPS SAINTS,2030Z,5710,12
5520325,ETABLISSEMENTS ADRIEN RIQUIER,,80570 DARGNIES,4674B,5710,12
5540380,SNC COMTE ET CIE,PHARMACIE COMTE,04000 DIGNE LES BAINS,4773Z,5202,11
5541552,ETABLISSEMENTS BONNET FRERES,,04370 BEAUVEZER,5610C,5499,03
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Include your question please, what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Is anything making it into your elasticsearch?

Comment: It's easier to debug this without ES in the mix by using the commented out `stdout` output. This is most likely a parsing issue.

Comment: I tried with your filter and output (input via stdin) and the data was successfully parsed and stored in ES. So I don't understand what is your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I've tried with MAC but it's not working? It's running but never finished!

Comment: I see that your problem is logstash never finished. Not sure what you mean by logstash never finished. After starting logstash it keeps waiting for input. As soon as there is new input it puts into ES. So in your case the data has been loaded into ES once the file has been read and thus it is waiting for some new data in the file. try putting in new record in your file and you will see it in your ES.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of [elasticsearch_loader](https://github.com/Moshe/elasticsearch_loader)
If you just want to load CSV data into elasticsearch you can use elasticsearch_loader
I wrote ESL for this exact problem

You can download it with pip:

```
pip install elasticsearch-loader
```

And then you will be able to load csv/json/parquet files into elasticsearch by issuing:

```
elasticsearch_loader --index ereputation --type incident csv input1.csv input2.csv
```

Comment: Thanks so much, your module works well for my case :)